# Getting started with DFP(Double-click For Publishers) banner ads in Android App

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I have admob banner ads integrated in my Android app, but I want to show only 'House Ads' and no Google 3rd party ads.

For this, I got a suggestion from Admob team, that I can use [DFP](https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com/solutions/) for the same, below is their reply:

"In AdMob it is not directly possible to disable all third-party ad networks from serving in mediation.  What you can do is to deprioritize the networks in your mediation stack (based on eCPM values) in order to fetch ads from desired sources.

Or, you can check out DFP, which allows you to set up and manage your own inventory.  DFP also integrates with the Mobile Ads SDK, so that means you can use your existing code base to make requests to the DFP network."

I've been digging into this since then, but found nowhere to start from.

They say I need to create an Inventory, but I'm not finding this tab anywhere.
Anyone? Worked with this, please guide how to add customized ad and generate ad unit.

Below is the link for adding DFP to android app:

[DFP integration in Android app](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear if this is a programming question or DFP configuration problem. I'm assuming you/your company has signed up for the correct DFP account. i.e. one that can do custom creative (ad artwork) https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/account_types

Comment: This is DFP configuration problem. They said, you ought to have Adsense account for DFP, so I have adsense account and logged into it in the same browser window. But still, whenever I try to login to DFP small business, it redirects me to DFP home page and asks for sign-in again.

Comment: @pratiti-systematix Did you find any solution. Even I am facing this issue.